# Entity Framework Core 6 (preview) forces me to use .AsEnumerable()

Tags: c#, linq, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I have updated from .net5 to .net6 preview in my project, and I'm having an issue with Entity Framework Core.

These queries were working fine in EF Core 5, however, they force me to do `.AsEnumerable()` to work in EF Core 6, which uses like double the memory it was using before. It looks like it should be possible to do (specially because it was working fine in EF Core 5), maybe I should be configuring something different to be able to make these queries?

```
var _data1 = _dbContext.Dataset1
                       .Where(f => f.PostedDate >= DateSince && f.PostedDate <= DateUntil)
                       .AsEnumerable();

var _orders = _dbContext.Orders
                        .Where(o => _data1.Select(f => f.OrderID).Contains(o.OrderID))
                        .AsEnumerable();

var _itms = _dbContext.Items
                      .Where(i => _orders.Select(o => o.OrderID).Contains(i.OrderId))
                      .AsEnumerable();

foreach(var order in _orders )
{
    var itms  = _itms?.Where(i => i.OrderId == order.OrderID);
    //...
}
```

**Update:**
This is the exception thrown whithout .AsEnumerable()

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(o => DbSet()
> .Where(f => f.PostedDate >= __DateSince_0 && f.PostedDate <= __DateUntil_1)
> .Select(f => f.OrderID)
> .Contains(o.OrderID))' could not be translated.
> Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to
> client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
> 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: Did you actually measure the memory used or are you making a guess?

Comment: "they force me to do .AsEnnumerable()" - can you elaborate how you are forced to do this?  Are you getting exceptions?

Comment: Looks like it can be written by one translatable query. But I cannot understand which final result is needed.

Comment: @palindrom: The details I'm talking about are in the VS debugger, it went from 200MB to +400MB while making the same query.

Comment: @Xerillio  When not using .AsEnnumerable() I got the error "entity framework 6 The LINQ expression could not be translated."

Comment: Sounds like you should be asking this at the EF Core repository. But, since it's a preview, it's not guaranteed to work anyway.

Comment: Do you want to use AsQueryable()? AsEnumerable force to elaborate the query than you have much memory allocation...

Comment: @Den I tried that, but it throws the same exception. I updated the post with the exception details

Comment: What are the tipe of datesince, dateUntil and f.postedDate?

Comment: @Den they are DateTime types

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to work around this issue by using navigation properties and grouping the results together, so that you only end up with one LINQ query.

```
var _groupedItems = _dbContext.Items
                              .Includes(i => i.Order)
                              .ThenIncludes(o => o.Dataset1)
                              .Where(f => f.Order.Dataset1.PostedDate >= DateSince && f.Order.Dataset1.PostedDate <= DateUntil)
                              .GroupBy(i => i.Order)
                              .Select(g => new
                              {
                                  Order = g.Key,
                                  Items = g.ToList()
                              });

foreach(var itemGroup in _groupedItems)
{
    var itms  = itemGroup.Items;
    //...
}
```

Comment: This is very useful and, for sure, I can improve my queries, however, I was wondering why it would stop working updating from EF5 to EF6

Comment: I hope you don't see it as a critique, I know that wasn't the point, I was only trying to help you get past this (hopefully temporary) problem. It would probably be best to address this issue in the ef6 repo as well: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues